# Reparametrization of Vector Fields in R2

Tags: vector-analysis

[image]

I'm having trouble determining if this is an orientation-preserving or an orientation-reversing reparametrization.

Comment: Presumably you mean reparameterization of paths (along which you'll computing the path integral of $\bf F$). In any case, it's hard to say much without knowing how $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are related. Could you include some more context, as well as what've you already worked out/tried?

Comment: This actually all of the information I am given for this problem.

I'm a bit unsure of what to do with vector field being in R2. In my textbook, I only see where the vector fields are in R3

Comment: Without definitions of what $\rho, \sigma$ are, the integrals aren't even defined, so nothing more can be said.